# Tengo Problemas con este código en Angular al utilizar ValidatorFn

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando utilizar el siguiente control personalizado pero no logro entender porque me marca todo con error, si alguien pude darme una mano le agradezco.

```
nombreValidadorParametrizable(minLong: number): ValidatorFn { 
  return (control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } | null  => {
  const l = control.value.toString().trim().length;
  if (l > 0 && l < minLong) {
     return {minLongNombre: true};
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Probé tu código y te falta una llave para cerrar después del `return null` fuera de eso lo demás funciona correctamente.

Comment: No funciono corregí y sigue el mismo problema

Comment: Entonces comparte mas información de tu código, el problema puede que resida en otra parte, así mismo comparte el error que te aparece, si son capturas mejor aún.

Comment: Disculpa mi falta de experiencia aqui me podrías indicar donde agrego mas info para no abrir una nuieva pregunta

Comment: Hay un link que dice editar. abajo de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

`null` significa que la validación es correcta. Retornar un objeto como `{minLongNombre: true}` es para mandar un mensaje de error. Eso signifca que por ejemplo, cualquier cosa que este entre 0 y 10 te dará siempre error. Si es menor que 0 y mayor que 10. La validación va a funcionar.

Esta linea:

```
 if (l > 0 && l < minLong) {
     return {minLongNombre: true};
  }
  return null;
```

Debe estar al revés :

```
 if (l > 0 && l < minLong) {
     return null;
  }
  return {minLongNombre: true};
```